# Grails Spring Security required fields

Tags: grails, spring-security

According to [spring-security-core documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/4%20Required%20and%20Optional%20Domain%20Classes.html#4.1%20Person%20Class) the only fields required in the User class are

```
String username
String password
boolean enabled
```

Though, after loging-in with my correct username and password, I get the following error:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: accountExpired
>   for class: doit.recruiter.User

which makes me think that *accountExpired*, *accountLocked* and *passwordExpired* are in fact required. How can I make my User domain class to work with only username/password/enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a bit misleading. The default implementation of the plugin uses a grails wrapper around the implementing class User for the User interface in spring security. This interface requires the three fields you don't want to have, and because of this the whole plugin also implements this.

The code that is failing for you would be found in the default user details implementation:

```
    boolean enabled = enabledPropertyName ? user."$enabledPropertyName" : true
    boolean accountExpired = accountExpiredPropertyName ? user."$accountExpiredPropertyName" : false
    boolean accountLocked = accountLockedPropertyName ? user."$accountLockedPropertyName" : false
    boolean passwordExpired = passwordExpiredPropertyName ? user."$passwordExpiredPropertyName" : false
```

The way around this would be to implement your own UserDetailsService and simply set the values to false hard coded. Alternatively just have the fields as transient properties in your domain class with getters that return false.

Custom user details recipe can be found here:
http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html